# Can I trust a MongoDB collection as a task queue?

Tags: mongodb, database

I've got one of my applications using Mongo as its primary DB, which works fine and fits my data.

Now I need to add another process to the app, that will handle tasks in the background.

**What should never happen** is the same task getting executed twice.
That means: When querying the DB again for tasks, after they got marked as done (even if they got marked 0.0001 milliseconds ago), I want to be sure the status is correct.

It always worked fine for me when using PostgreSQL or MySQL, but I heard a lot that MongoDB is unreliable because it stages inserts to actually be executed later.

Should I worry for my case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `db.collection.findAndModify()` which will ensure a great level of atomicity. Something like below. This will ensure that you are working on a document that is already marked as done and no other process can fetch that document.

```
db.car.findAndModify({
  query: { task : 'new' },
  sort: { _id : 1 },
  update: { $set: { task: 'done'} }
});
```

Refer documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) .

Comment: Assuming only one process would work with the collection, can I pull it off without `findAndModify`? My ORM doesn't support it, and I'd rather keep my code consistent.

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: http://docs.mongoengine.org/changelog.html?highlight=find_and_modify I see in the changelog.